# Proper way to create a Mono/Flux from a service that returns a future

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mono, completable-future, spring-webflux

How do I properly handle Monos built from futures?

I'm trying to get my head around Spring Reactive (and Spring 5), watching all the videos and reading all the blogs I can find, but they all seem to stop short of doing something slightly more than just querying a database, or something else trivial.

I'm making use of the new AWS 2.0 SDK which uses `CompletableFuture`'s for most things. Using a service to create a new instance, my method looks like this

```
public Mono<RunInstancesResponse> create(Instance instance) {
    RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = RunInstancesRequest.builder()
            .instanceType(instance.getInstanceType())
            .imageId(instance.getImageId())
            .securityGroupIds(instance.getSecurityGroupIds())
            .keyName(instance.getKeyName())
            .minCount(1)
            .maxCount(1)
            .tagSpecifications(createTags(instance))
            .build();

    CompletableFuture<RunInstancesResponse> future = client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

    future.whenComplete((response, error) -> {
        response.reservation().instances().stream().map(aws -> Instance.builder()
                .imageId(aws.imageId())
                .build()
        ).forEach(instanceRepository::save);

    });

    return Mono.fromFuture(future);
}
```

My understanding here is I'm returning a `Mono` of type `RunInstancesResponse` almost immediately, while the `future.whenComplete` will do it's thing just whenever.

I'm calling that from my route handler which looks like

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Instance.class)
            .flatMap(createService::create)
            .flatMap(i -> ServerResponse.accepted().build());
}
```

Now this almost works as I'd expect, however there are a couple of key things wrong I don't know how to solve.

1.) The `whenComplete` is never called and I believe this is because I've not subscribed to it.

2.) The server doesn't respond to the client until the `whenComplete` is done (about 2.5 seconds) which isn't ideal as I'd want it to respond immediately then update the client when the `whenComplete` is called.

I get the feeling my entire service and handler is just completely wrong way to do things.

I'd love some examples of how I should handle futures in a service where it's called from a route handler with either a `Mono` or `Flux` type.

Comment: Points 1. and 2. seem contradictory since you say that `whenComplete()` is never called and that you only get a response after `whenComplete()` is executed. The way you call `whenComplete()` seems fine to me however, but maybe the problem is with your threadpool size which does not allow the concurrency you need?

Comment: Did you have a look at Mono.fromFuture(future)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an [open source library](https://github.com/tddmonkey/reactor-aws) that wraps SQS, SNS and DynamoDb to make this a bit easier.  To avoid a link only answer, you can apply the following to it:

```
public Mono<ChangeMessageVisibilityResult> changeMessageVisibility(String queueUrl, String receiptHandle, Integer visibilityTimeout) {
    return Mono.create(subscriber -> amazonClient.changeMessageVisibilityAsync(queueUrl, receiptHandle, visibilityTimeout, AmazonWebServiceRequestAsyncHandler.valueEmittingHandlerFor(subscriber)));
  }
```

The handler that is passed converts between the 2 worlds:

```
public class AmazonWebServiceRequestAsyncHandler<RQ extends AmazonWebServiceRequest, RS> implements AsyncHandler<RQ, RS> {
    private final MonoSink<? super RS> subscriber;
    private boolean shouldEmitValue;

    private AmazonWebServiceRequestAsyncHandler(MonoSink<? super RS> subscriber, boolean shouldEmitValue) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
        this.shouldEmitValue = shouldEmitValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception exception) {
        subscriber.error(exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(RQ request, RS response) {
        if (shouldEmitValue) {
            subscriber.success(response);
        } else {
            subscriber.success();
        }
    }

    public static <RQ extends AmazonWebServiceRequest, RS> AsyncHandler<RQ, RS> valueEmittingHandlerFor(final MonoSink<? super RS> subscriber) {
        return new AmazonWebServiceRequestAsyncHandler<>(subscriber, true);
    }

    public static <RQ extends AmazonWebServiceRequest> AsyncHandler<RQ, Void> voidHandlerFor(MonoSink<? super Void> subscriber) {
        return new AmazonWebServiceRequestAsyncHandler<>(subscriber, false);
    }
}
```